# Can a Chinese tablet be used as an android emulator device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can a Chinese tablet be used as an Android emulator device?

Because my eclipse cannot detect any device, and the same with Samsung Kies.

Does anyone know how it can be connected?

Comment: FYI, everything from iPad to Samsung Tab is made in China. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's not dependent on what make the tablet is, it has everything to do with what Android version is running.

Just connect it to your PC and make sure in the Android settings that debugging on the device is allowed.

Check this out for example: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is just the virtual device used from the sdk to allow you to develop without a real device, so actually you're asking to us if you can run your apps with your device.

Yes, obviously.

If you're running Android you can install your apks on your tablet, just connect it and select "USB device" instead of "emulator", otherwise the emulator will start. Don't forget to add "Debugging" in your settings.

If you cannot interface your tablet with your pc (due to usb drivers issues, or others) you can still upload your apk somewhere and install it (like send it to you by mail, or upload it on your Dropbox folder).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just like what Gerald says, it is not dependent to the device but to the OS.

**To use an Android device as an emulator, you need to:**

1. **Install the ADB driver corresponding to your device on your PC.** If you didn't install it, then your device won't be recognized on your PC. The ADB drivers for Samsung devices can be found on Samsung Kies.
2. **USB debugging must be enabled on your phone.** To enable USB debugging on your phone, go to > Settings > Applications > Development and check "USB Debugging". If you don't enable it, then you can't use your phone/ table as an Android Emulator Device.